# Android OnActivityResult gave me a NULL value with getStringExtra()

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, onactivityresult

I'm trying to get a response inside the onActivityResult from an uri intent. However, it is always -1 as resultCode and null as Intent data.

```
  private fun startMyFunction(call: MethodCall) {
    val app: String? = call.argument("app")
    val url: String? = call.argument("url")

    try {
      val uri = Uri.parse(url)
      
      val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
      intent.setPackage(app)

      if (activity?.let { intent.resolveActivity(it.packageManager) } == null) {
        this.success("activity_unavailable")
        return
      }

      activity?.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeNumber)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      Log.e("my_app", ex.toString())
      this.success("failed_to_open_app")
    }
  }
```

```
  private fun success(o: String) {
    if (!hasResponded) {
      hasResponded = true
      result?.success(o)
    }
  }
```

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?): Boolean {
    if (requestCodeNumber == requestCode && result != null) {
      Log.d("onActivityResult - response - ", data.toString())
      if (data != null) {
        try {
          val response = data.getStringExtra("response")!!
          this.success(response) 
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
          this.success("invalid_response - Exception")
        }
      } else {
        this.success("user_cancelled - Null data")
      }
    }
    return true
  }
```

I have read many of the similar situations here on StackOverflow, as well as on Google, but none of them have helped me in my case

For ref -
https://github.com/GJJ2019/upi_pay/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/drenther/upi_pay/UpiPayPlugin.kt

Comment: Why do you think that a random app choosen by the user for ACTION_VIEW would return a result? And if it did had put your extra? Use startActivity().

Comment: @blackapps I have very limited knowledge of kotlin/intent. Basically I'm am trying to to develop an app in flutter but wile debugging I found that the I am getting null response, would be grateful if you can provide some example to fix. Thanks

Comment: What response are you wanting back from the other activity? You are currently opening a URI in whatever app happens to be able to open a URI of that type. No response should be expected back from the other app just for viewing something.

Comment: I am launching an upi app to do transition through URI and in return expecting transition status as string "response" @Tenfour04

Comment: Are you wanting to launch a specific app whose documentation declares that it will return a String `response`? If not, there's no reason you can expect some specific return value like that. If you want to launch a specific app, you need to use the package name of that app in the Intent you use to start it.

Comment: Yes I am launching an specific app which I am passing through the method call (here  - val app: String? = call.argument("app") ) and it is mentioned in the app documentation that app will return response String. For me the intent is working fine i am able to open the app and do the transition but inside onActivityResult while logging ( Here - Log.d("onActivityResult - response - ", data.toString()) ) its always null. That is what is crashing my app @Tenfour04

Comment: Can you link the documentation that describes how this app returns a result?

Comment: Please have a look at below document heading B.Intent related https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/npci/upi/circular/2017/Circular18_BankCompliances_to_enbaleUPIMerchantecosystem_0.pdf . Also GooglePay (earlier it was Google tez) work similarly. here is the repo google shared officially for Gpay integration https://github.com/googletez/inapp-payment-samples/blob/master/java/app/src/main/java/com/google/tezdemo/inappsample/MainActivity.java